When can you neglect terms like $a_n a_{n+1}$ or $a_n^\dagger a_{n+1}^\dagger$?
I am looking for a detailed explanation of when and why we can neglect terms like $a_n a_{n+1}$ or $a_n^\dagger a_{n+1}^\dagger$ in Hamiltonians like
$$
H = \omega \sum_n a^\dagger_n a_n + \lambda\sum_{n} \left(a_n a_{n+1} + a_n^\dagger a_{n+1}^\dagger + a^\dagger_n a_{n+1} +a^\dagger_{n+1}a_n \right) \approx \omega \sum_n a^\dagger_n a_n + \lambda\sum_{n} \left( a^\dagger_n a_{n+1} +a^\dagger_{n+1}a_n \right).$$
I've seen this arise in the context of quantum circuits and other models where one encounters interactions of the form $x_n x_{n+1}$ , $p_n p_{n+1}$, $x_n p_{n+1}$, etc. The typical explanation given is that "$\omega \gg \lambda$" or that "in the rotating wave approximation, terms like $a_n a_{n+1}$ oscillate fast and can be ignored".
In the rotating frame, I see that transformations like
$$H(t) = \exp(-it\omega\sum_n a^\dagger_n a_n)H\exp(it\omega\sum_n a^\dagger_n a_n)$$
leave a fast oscillating factor in front of terms like $a_n a_{n+1}$ but why/when can it be disregarded?
I don't see how $\omega \gg \lambda$ is relevant for the approximation.

Edit 1, based on the comments:

I will stress that I am looking for a way of justifying neglecting $\lambda \sum_n (a_n a_{n+1} + a_n^\dagger a_{n+1}^\dagger)$ but NOT the hopping term $\lambda \sum_n (a_n^\dagger a_{n+1} + a_n a_{n+1}^\dagger)$. I suspect this will likely involve talking about the spectrum/eigenvectors of $H$ in a particular limit.
I have for instance seen this arise in the context of quantum electrical circuits. For instance, one can approximate a chain of capacitively/inductively coupled harmonic LC oscillators to a hopping chain. That is, I can show that the Hamiltonian of a chain of capacitively/inductively coupled harmonic LC oscillators is
$$ H = \sum_n \alpha_n p_n^2 + \beta_n x_n^2 + \lambda_n x_n x_{n+1}.$$
Note that the coupling term $x_n x_{n+1} = (a^\dagger_n + a_n)(a^\dagger_{n+1} + a_{n+1})$ yields exactly my first Hamiltonian. However, following reference "Bloch oscillations and Wannier-Stark ladder in the coupled LC circuits (Bahmani 2020)" equation (12), one claims that if $\omega \gg \lambda$ then
$$H \approx \sum_n \omega_n a^\dagger_n a_n + \lambda_n\sum_{n} \left( a^\dagger_n a_{n+1} +a^\dagger_{n+1}a_n \right),$$
if I understand the ref correctly.


Just to clarify where you are in your understanding: Are you familiar with the RWA in the context of two-level systems and how it works in that simplest case?  I imagine it's the same here, and so that would be a first good case to look at.  It's essentially a resonance condition.

@march Safest to say no at this point I think

A dumb answer is that the Hamiltonian is schematically $\omega a^2 + \lambda a^2$, and the approximation $\omega \gg \lambda$ means you can ignore the second term. Are you looking for more than that, and if so can you be a bit more specific on where you get stuck? Like, "when is $\omega \gg \lambda$ true", or "why does the first term come with a factor of $\omega$ and the second a factor of $\lambda$", or "does this approximation of the Hamiltonian operator work for every state in the Hilbert space"?

You'll want to look at how the RWA works for two-level systems, because it illuminates both the physics and the mathematics of this approximation. You can start here.

@march I dont see the connection yet: the RWA it's an approximation for a time dependent Hamiltonian term. My Hamiltonian is time-independent. Furthermore, the RWA relies on the fact that the $\omega_d$ drive frequency is very near the frequency of the atom $\omega_0$, i.e. near resonance. Again,  I don't see anything close to that happening to my Hamiltonian (is that related to $\omega \gg \lambda$?).

Would you be able to provide a specific reference where this sort of approximation occurs for better context? And also explain what about Andrew's comment isn't satisfactory?

@JudahReynolds well, I don't see how to understand Andrew's comment: if you ignore the second term you don't have the $a_n a_{n+1}$ term but you also don't have the $a^\dagger_n a_{n+1}$ terms either which is not what the question seeks. Having said that, I will add an edit to the question to clarify.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/759453/247642, https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/616701/247642

This question is similar to: Rotating wave approximation and conservation of energy. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@RogerV. It does answer my question, good spot. What would happen with my bounty?

Apparently the bounty is lost (I initially thought that it would be restituted to the person who asked the question.) I am glad that you got the answer that you needed... and too bad for me for not getting the bounty. I admit I was too lazy to write an answer - I don't like posting two sentence answers to bounty questions, while  writing an essay on the RWA would be too much work... and can be found in books without second quantization, which is what really obscures the issue here (but you seem to be able to see through this.)

@RogerV. No worries! I left the clarification I was needing in your answer to the post you shared. PD: Second quantisation is what made me "understand" QM, so I guess everyone is different!

I had a new answer I was thinking of adding! Oh well, it doesn't quite fit in the other question's answers, just a different perspective. Think about the Heisenberg equations $dA/dt=i[H,A]/\hbar$ for the evolution of any operator $A$. In the interaction picture (rotating frame, not rotating wave approximation), the operator is actually $a e^{-i\omega_a t}$. If you integrate that part of the Hamiltonian in a classical way, you find $A(t)-A(0)=i[a b,A]\int_0^t e^{i(\omega_a+\omega_b)t} dt/\hbar$, ignoring temporal commutation. The integral gives $1/(\omega_a+\omega_b)$, which is small

@QuantumMechanic feel free to add it in more detail! Bedsides, bounty is still open for grabs: better it doesn't go to waste ;)

@FriendlyLagrangian I don't think I can answer anymore, this one is closed! So I edited my answer at the linked question. Thank you though
